# how can I create a list of objects to stream data?

Tags: python

I need to create a list to save objects like [MyClass1,MyClass2], and then later loop and execute `run` to get all data from all objects, can I do this?

```py
class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
     return 1
```

output
1
2

Comment: Where's the 2 coming from? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: What have you already tried? This has multiple steps, so I want to understand where you're stuck exactly.

Comment: I am trying to figure how can I do this? `Class_*.run()`

Comment: What is `Class_*` supposed to mean? Are you referring to `MyClass1, MyClass2`?

Comment: that's exactly I what i meant .yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `2` in the output is a typo (or from a hypothetical `MyClass2`) you can initialize a list of objects and run them inside of a list comprehension:

```py
class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        return 1

objects = [MyClass1("one"), MyClass1("two"), MyClass1("three")]

print([obj.run() for obj in objects])
# Result: [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what I was looking